# How to pass data from an element to an action in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have the following code, which leverages Bootstrap's button styling and functionality:

```
import React from 'react';

import DashboardActions from '../../action/dashboard.js';

export class StatFilter extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selection: this.props.initialSelection
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="btn-group">
                <button ref="viewButton" type="button" className="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        onChange={DashboardActions.seeValue.bind(null, React.findDOMNode(this.refs.viewButton).value)}>
                    <span>{this.props.initialSelection}</span>
                    <span className="caret"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a>Revenue</a></li>
                    <li><a>Trends</a></li>
                    <li><a>Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Inside the `render` function, my `StatFilter` attaches an action to an event. What I want to happen with that bind is that the value of the `viewButton` button is passed to the action. In other words, when the value of the button changes, `StatFilter` will dispatch an action letting my app know that its value has changed.

How I'm trying to do this is by using `bind()` to pass the value of the `viewButton` to the action. This, however, gives me the warning:

> t is accessing getDOMNode or findDOMNode inside its render(). render() should be a pure function of props and state. It should never access something that requires stale data from the previous render, such as refs. Move this logic to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate instead.

And the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Although I'm certain I'm doing this wrong, is the warning telling me something too? Should I be handling all of this logic in the render function? If not, then where should I put it? Also, how come the above code does not work?

Comment: Why -1? I did my research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `findDOMNode` within the render method return is the problem.  You can not call a function directly in the event handler, but rather must pass the event handler a callback.  This won't invoke a function call when the component renders, but rather when an event occurs.

```
export class StatFilter extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selection: this.props.initialSelection
        };
    }
    handleChange(){
        DashboardActions.seeValue(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.viewButton).value);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="btn-group">
                <button ref="viewButton" type="button" className="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <span>{this.props.initialSelection}</span>
                    <span className="caret"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a>Revenue</a></li>
                    <li><a>Trends</a></li>
                    <li><a>Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```